# Front lateral raise from deadlift position

Tags: strength

I've been doing an exercise where I go into deadlift stance with an empty barbell placed a couple feet in front of me so my arms are outstretched. To elaborate, the barbell is far away from my center of gravity and stays that way for the duration of the movement.

Then while staying crouched I do an explosive front lateral raise until the bar is overhead.

What am I accomplishing by doing this?

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve but what you are doing sounds not very healthy. .. you will surely achieve some back pain after some time. You are trying to do some sort of snatch, but starting with wrong body position and bar movement that will lead to an injury for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to avoid this. You're doing a [barbell front raise](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/DeltoidAnterior/BBFrontRaise.html), but adding in a ballistic motion with your "explosive" aspect.

The front raise is basically a body builder isolation exercise, and with all shoulder activities you want to adhere to strict form given the ease of injury.

If you want to get a bar over your head, learn the (quite complicated) [snatch](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/OlympicLifts/Snatch.html). With the snatch, the force to get the bar overhead is via the legs and hips, the arms are simply there to act as ropes at the bottom and support struts at the top. Any "lifting" with your arms is bad, as you'll never be able to lift with your arms what you can explode with your hips and legs.

If you want to exercise your shoulders, I highly recommend the seems-easy-but-it's-not [barbell overhead press](http://stronglifts.com/overhead-press/). This is a very difficult lift which humbles even the strongest people. It's also terrific for shoulder development.